# Freeform Lite - Dynamic Notifications

Tags: craft3, plugin-freeform, solspace

I am wondering if you can offer some help with an issues I am having. I am using Freeform Lite and I have a hidden field with the entry title as the value.

Is it possible to use that value for sending email notifications dependant on the value.

[image]

Basically I want to use that hidden field so that I can send the notifications to the location email address e.g. Bishopbriggs to bishopbriggs@hellocovault.com and Bellshill to bellshill@hellocovault.com etc.

I have tried the dynamic recipeint field but I can't get that to pre select the correct option.

You can see the form here - http://hellocovault.com/locations/bellshill